# Problem with System.Thread.Timer execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

Performing data retrieval from socket.ReceiveFromAsync, there is some functionality to check for packages from sender to receiver. There is a certain class that stores statistics and all data for transmission. After sending the packet I start the timer to wait for a response, ideally I get a response and start killing the timer. But it happens that the response packet does not come back until the time specified in the timer, I send a repeat. This is where the weirdness doesn't always happen, but often it is. I haven't received the packet, the timer function starts to run, and I send the packet to repeat the timer on hold, at which point the packet comes in, such as a delayed packet, and I destroy the timer. but after the time of delay the function starts to run on sending a repeat as if I hadn't destroyed the timer.
I started to output the log from the ID of the thread in which the packets are received and the timer is executed, and in which thread the timer is destroyed, the destruction and retry of the false alarm is executed in different threads. How do I solve this problem ?

Receive code :

```
 public void ReceiveAsync()
 {

        SocketAsyncEventArgs recieveArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        recieveArgs.SetBuffer(new byte[_data_size], 0, _data_size);
        recieveArgs.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        recieveArgs.Completed += ProcessRecievedPacket;

        if (!_socket.ReceiveFromAsync(recieveArgs))
            ProcessRecievedPacket(this, recieveArgs);
    }


public void ProcessRecievedPacket(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            Monitor.Enter(_lock_receive);
            if (e.BytesTransferred > 0 && e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
            {
                ReceiveAsync();
 ...
 }
```

Sending:

record is a class containing sending statistics.

```
    record._start_wait_crl(onEventLog);
    SendData(remoteAddr, data);


internal static void _start_wait_crl(this StatusNodeRecord record, _OnEventLog onEventLog)
    {
        try
        {
            record._timer_wait_crl_acp = new Timer((e) =>
            {
                StatusNodeRecord _record = (StatusNodeRecord)e;
                record._lockSlimDispose.EnterWriteLock();
                try
                {
                        _record._socket.SendData(_record.Key.Item1, data);
                        _record?._timer_wait_crl_acp?.Change(_record._time_wait, Timeout.Infinite);
                }
                finally
                {
                    record._lockSlimDispose.ExitWriteLock();
                }
            }, record, record._time_wait, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            onEventLog?.Invoke(record, MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name, $"EXCEPTION::{ex.Message}. <-----------------------------------------------");
        }
    }
```

The moment I receive confirmation on the sender's side:

```
internal static void _dispose_wait_crl(this StatusNodeRecord record, _OnEventLog onEventLog)
    {
        record._lockSlimDispose.EnterWriteLock();
        try
        {
                record?._timer_wait_crl_acp?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
                record? _timer_wait_crl_acp?Dispose();
                record._timer_wait_crl_acp = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            record._lockSlimDispose.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
```

Help for a week I've been getting one and the same error The object doesn't exist, on a false positive the timer is already destroyed, and on a false positive it turns out that the methods should update the time and send a request, but it won't update the destroyed one.

Comment: Why do you use two synchronization primitives (`_lock_receive` and `record._lockSlimDispose`)? What is protected by the first, and what is protected by the second?

Comment: It seems that you are using **Async** methods (`ReceiveFromAsync`, `ReceiveAsync`), but there is no `async`/`await` keywords in your code ... are you aware of *Asynchronous programming* ??? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.receivefromasync?view=netcore-3.1 ReceiveFromAsync - is Async method this method use by socket without connect method.  _lock_receive I'll crawl into a completely different reception class, no problem. The problem is that when using the timer.dispose() method, it is not destroyed if there is already a function that is in another thread pool, there is no need to put the timer on hold and repeat the operation if necessary, but the incoming packet on the socket is in a random thread, and it starts the destruct function.

Comment: If abstractly there is a class that performs functions of receiving and sending data not mediocrely in socket, there is a class that handles them, in the same class that handles them there is a function that performs sending and processing of incoming packets. here's the problem, all incoming packets come from different streams judging by Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, sometimes they match but most often do not. So it turns out that the sending and initialization of the initial timer is in the same thread,

Comment: but the link to the timer is started in the general class statistics, and the package that receives the class as a confirmation and must remove the timer in another thread and often it turns out that if the function has already started to work for a second time, then after the destruction is a few milliseconds and the execution of this function occurs. Although the timer has already been destroyed.